# Why is my fresh pasta tough?

Tags: dough, pasta, kneading

I picked up a Marcato Pasta Maker and followed the recipe included to make both fettuccine and ravioli. The [instructions](http://www.marcato.it/Images/Catalog/Articles/Attachments/02AT150CLR_manuale-marcato-atlas-150.pdf) that came with the machine offer two basic recipes:

- 500g soft wheat flour
- 5 eggs

or

- 250g soft wheat flour
- 250g durum wheat (semolina flour)
- 5 eggs

I've tried both methods, using King Arthur All Purpose flour for the soft wheat flour, and Caputo Semola for the semolina. In both cases, I found the resulting pasta to be tough and have a considerable bite.  I tried cooking both pastas for a bit longer than recommended with the same results.  I am using the recommended thinness that the machine produces as well. The recipe notes to knead for 10mins or until the dough is smooth. I have been kneading it for 10-12 mins and still find that it isn't quite "smooth"; but I'm no expert on what that is.

I would prefer a more delicate, soft, and melt in your mouth type of pasta. Instead I am getting something with quite a bit of bite and that is quite tough. What can I do to improve the result to my liking?

[image: after kneading]
[image: the marcato making ravioli]

Answer (score 3):

Try using double-zero (00) flour, available from Italian specialty stores. You might also prefer a recipe that uses more egg yolks, or only yolks and not whole eggs. For example: https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/fresh-pasta.

Comment: Nice, I have 00 on hand for Neapolitan pizza already. Would I substitute 00 for all flour or use both 00 and semolina? I can easily add more eggs or yolks too and report back the results.